# Question on hold answer marking

Tags: discussion

I know that you can't really answer a question once it is on hold, but can the OP mark an answer as correct if it is on hold?

Comment: Someone should answer No, just so there's *some* variety in the answers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

All "on hold" or "closed" does is prevent new answers from being added. Existing answers can still be voted on and edited, for instance. And, yes, the Asker can mark one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** OP can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the question has answers then an answer can be accepted regardless of whether or not the question is on hold or closed.