# Why is my post OnHold with as reason Your Question is Not Clear?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a post and somebody responded with a good solution for me, but the funny thing is, site admins put my post OnHold and said *Your post is not clear*

If my post is not clear so how can someone answer my question?

Here is a link to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517482/detailsview-change-button-text-in-css

Comment: For one thing, you write like a teenager. Chatspeak, random caps (even in your username), overuse of emoticons, the list goes on. Why make your posts unnecessarily difficult or annoying to read? If it's this bad on meta, I dare not click through to see your actual question. Whoever answered your question is probably *incredibly* forgiving and willing to take the time to figure out what you're saying.

Comment: Read the comment on your question.

Comment: You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You received one answer and it worked for you but still you did not accept it. Why? any reason for that.

Comment: As an aside it was closed by ordinary users not site admins (moderators have a ♦ next to their name - like BoltClock above).

Comment: Well for your record my username is Ali ParLouS and it's my nick name for 10 years so don't be judge me so fast, and to answer YoungHobbit i have to say i've try many time to do this and problem is post in OnHold as i said.. Thank you DavidPostill i will read your tips for sure. Ok i didn't know this website access ordinary user to HoldOn a post or somthing.. Thank You David..

Comment: Sure, make your username as pretty as you like (I've had mine for 10 years, too) - just don't extend that to all of your writing. We expect proper writing here, not chatspeak, even in comments.

Comment: Ok, I do my best on next question or answer

Comment: I think you should be able to accept the answer if you wish to. It is allowed to accept answers on the post. on-hold, does not allow further new answers to the post. [Link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258682/2254048).

Comment: Although it is nice of you to point out that feature @YoungHobbit but there is no requirement to accept an answer. Users are free to accept an answer or not. and if they decide not to accept there is no reason needed.

Comment: I checked my question again right now and i can't find any button like Accept Answer or Resolve or somthing

Comment: @rene Yes. I am aware that it is completely users choice to accept an answer or not. But OP has committed that he has received a good answer and it helped him, into solving the issue. Then OP also should accept the answer (of their choice). IMHO, that is the responsibility of OP to state that he has received the intended help from community.

Comment: @AliParLouS You should see and tick (right tick) symbol, just below the upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: Thank you @YoungHobbit, After all i did it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No site administrators and/or moderators were involved in closing your question, only normal users like you and me that gained enough reputation to gain the privilege to close vote on questions. I was one of the close voters.

Besides the poor layout and more text than code your question really missed either html markup  or the ASP.Net markup to make your question of much value for future visitors. There are is not enough context in your question.

That you got an answer that actually works for you is probably due to the mind boggling flexibility and experience of Steve than anything else.

Next time pay a little bit more attention to lay out, punctuation, spelling and grammar but above all add enough code/markup that makes it clear what you have and what you need so the answers don't need to invent or guess the code that is not in your question.

Comment: Thank you @rene i will keep it in my mind for next time

Comment: "mind boggling flexibility and experience of Steve" so... we need to 'fix' Steve?

Comment: You fix what you think needs fixing @Braiam